# Use Onload or ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i am using

```
$(document).ready()
```

What is the difference between this and

```
$(document).onload()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is triggered when only the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) becomes ready while [`onload`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event3.shtml) triggers when ***all resources*** of the page including [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), images, frames, etc have loaded.

See:

[$(document).ready vs. $(window).load](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/)

***Note*** that `ready` lies with jQuery not raw javascript so I assume you know that and that way comparison seems logical.

Comment: Note that the browser must support the underlying `DOMContentLoaded` event for the jQuery `ready` event to fire immediately when the document content is ready. IE may fire it a bit later; for other browsers without support, `ready` will fire at effectively the same time as `load`.

Answer (score 7):

.ready() is called as soon as the page code is downloaded and parsed.

.onload() is called when all the images/videos/etc are downloaded.

Use .ready() for jQuery to work best, unless you have a specific reason for waiting until onload().

Answer (score 2):

**.ready()**

> A function to execute after the DOM is ready.

-From the [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

**.onload()**

> The onload event occurs when the user agent finishes loading a window or all frames within a FRAMESET.

-From the [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html)

Answer (score 1):

All explained inside the [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready).

> The first thing that most Javascript
> programmers end up doing is adding
> some code to their program, similar to
> this:
>
> `window.onload = function(){ alert("welcome"); }`
>
> Inside of which is
> the code that you want to run right
> when the page is loaded.
> Problematically, however, the
> Javascript code isn't run until all
> images are finished downloading (this
> includes banner ads). The reason for
> using window.onload in the first place
> is that the HTML 'document' isn't
> finished loading yet, when you first
> try to run your code.
>
> To circumvent both problems, jQuery
> has a simple statement that checks the
> document and waits until it's ready to
> be manipulated, known as the ready
> event:

As an aside (and as [suggested](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) by yahoo) I always ensure my jquery/js scripts are included just before the body closing tag. That way you do not need to worry about window load or jquery ready functions.