# i want to call a jquery function on load of the page

Tags: jquery

I want to call a jquery function on load of the page. There is also another Javascript getting called onload of the body tag.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  //do something
});
```

Or if you already have the function, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  //do something
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
$(myFunction);
```

Both of the above are equivalent to `$(document).ready(function);`, they're just shortcuts.

Answer (score 8):

No problem - they won't conflict with each other:

```
$(window).load(function() {...});
```

or...

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

Use the second one if you don't need to wait for images and other external dependencies. It simply waits for the DOM to be "ready" (i.e., completely constructed).

---

Here's some good [introductory reading on the subject](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready), by the way.

Comment: The first should be `window`, it has the `onload` event :)

Comment: ... guess I should add that, yes, the window object of course had the load event. The jQuery convention though seems to be to use the load pseudo-event on the document object. So... you're right, but my code will still work :)

Comment: @jmar777 - It won't...here's a test to show it :) http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8XYpq/

Answer (score 3):

There is a jQquery handler called [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) that will do what you want.  It executes with the DOM is ready.  See also [Use Onload or ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197942/use-onload-or-ready) for a discussion about the differences between ready and onload.